# Where is current dhclient lease on RHEL7?

Tags: rhel, dhclient

I cannot find any of `dhclient.lease`on my RHEL7.4. There is no one in `/var/lib/dhclient`.

Comment: Is DHCP running on the system? You can also use `locate` to find it.

Comment: @NasirRiley, with DHCP do you mean dhclient? If yes, then yes, it's running.

Comment: Thanks @NasirRiley. Found one in `/var/lib/NetworkManager/` folder with use of `locate`.

Comment: You are welcome. I forget that it could also be in that location if `NetworkManager` is running``. I'll post it as an answer to show the question is resolved and so that it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `locate` command to find it.

If `NetworkManager` isn't running then it will be in this directory:

```
/var/lib/dhclient/
```

If `NetworkManager` is running then it will be in this directory:

```
var/lib/NetworkManager
```